# Snakemake-based software does not work on slurm cluster, while it works in the login node

Tags: python, anaconda, slurm, snakemake, genome

I am trying to run a snakemake-based software https://github.com/MeHelmy/princess with SLURM on our cluster https://gitlab.com/cigene/computational/orion-support.

In brief,
the issue is that when I run the software on the login node, it works. However, when I submit a slurm script to run this software, it gives me an error that `snakemake/temp file is not found.` It takes unrealistically long to finish the job without cluster, so I would really appreciate your help.

So far, we, the IT team and the developer have tried:

(1) check yaml file setting with our cluster managers - looks fine

(2) add `--latency-wait 120` - no visible change

(3) check if there is a restriction to delete temp files from the cluster - there is no such restriction

What I ran:

```
(base) [mariesai@cn-4 ~]$ module load PyYAML/5.1.2-GCCcore-8.3.0
(base) [mariesai@cn-4 ~]$ module load Miniconda3/4.7.10
(base) [mariesai@cn-4 ~]$ module load snakemake/5.30.1
(base) [mariesai@cn-4 ~]$ module load HTSlib 

The following have been reloaded with a version change:
  1) GCCcore/8.3.0 => GCCcore/9.3.0
  2) XZ/5.2.4-GCCcore-8.3.0 => XZ/5.2.5-GCCcore-9.3.0
  3) binutils/2.32-GCCcore-8.3.0 => binutils/2.34-GCCcore-9.3.0
  4) bzip2/1.0.8-GCCcore-8.3.0 => bzip2/1.0.8-GCCcore-9.3.0
  5) zlib/1.2.11-GCCcore-8.3.0 => zlib/1.2.11-GCCcore-9.3.0

(base) [mariesai@cn-4 princesstest]$ python3.7  /net/fs-1/Transpose/Software/princess/princess all -d $PWD/0406/2.without.e -r ont -s $PWD/test.fastq.gz --chr ssa18 -f /mnt/SCRATCH/kristenl/Reference/Simon_Sept2020.fasta -j 200  --rerun-incomplete --verbose
```

Error digest:

```
[Tue Apr  6 09:05:56 2021]
Error in rule readsStat:
    jobid: 6
    output: /net/cn-1/mnt/SCRATCH/princesstest/0406/2.without.e/statitics/raw_reads/reads_stat.txt
    conda-env: /net/cn-1/mnt/SCRATCH/princesstest/0406/2.without.e/.snakemake/conda/1b58da75
    shell:
        
        python scripts/rawcoverage.py -i /net/cn-1/mnt/SCRATCH/princesstest/0406/2.without.e/test.fastq.gz -o /net/cn-1/mnt/SCRATCH/princesstest/0406/2.without.e/statitics/raw_reads/reads_stat.txt -t 5
        
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)
    cluster_jobid: 12727829

Error executing rule readsStat on cluster (jobid: 6, external: 12727829, jobscript: /net/cn-1/mnt/SCRATCH/princesstest/0406/2.without.e/.snakemake/tmp.4xwny_7b/snakejob.readsStat.6.sh). For error details see the cluster log and the log files of the involved rule(s).
```

Log digest
slurm-12727829.out

```
Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
Missing files after 5 seconds:
/net/cn-1/mnt/SCRATCH/princesstest/0406/2.without.e/.snakemake/tmp.4xwny_7b
```

slurm-12727823.out

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 5
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   readsStat
    1
Select jobs to execute...

[Tue Apr  6 09:05:21 2021]
Job 0: Calculating read coverage statitics for: /net/cn-1/mnt/SCRATCH/princesstest/0406/2.without.e/test.fastq.gz


        python scripts/rawcoverage.py -i /net/cn-1/mnt/SCRATCH/princesstest/0406/2.without.e/test.fastq.gz -o /net/cn-1/mnt/SCRATCH/princesstest/0406/2.without.e/statitics/raw_reads/reads_stat.txt -t 5
        
Activating conda environment: /net/cn-1/mnt/SCRATCH/princesstest/0406/2.without.e/.snakemake/conda/1b58da75
Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 10 of /net/cn-1/mnt/SCRATCH/princesstest/0406/2.without.e/modules/stat.smk:
Job Missing files after 5 seconds:
/net/cn-1/mnt/SCRATCH/princesstest/0406/2.without.e/statitics/raw_reads/reads_stat.txt
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
Job id: 0 completed successfully, but some output files are missing. 0
  File "/cluster/software/snakemake/5.30.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 575, in handle_job_success
  File "/cluster/software/snakemake/5.30.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 254, in handle_job_success
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

slurm-12727825.out

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cores: 1 (use --cores to define parallelism)
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   readsStat
    1
Select jobs to execute...

[Tue Apr  6 09:05:46 2021]
Job 0: Calculating read coverage statitics for: /net/cn-1/mnt/SCRATCH/princesstest/0406/2.without.e/test.fastq.gz


        python scripts/rawcoverage.py -i /net/cn-1/mnt/SCRATCH/princesstest/0406/2.without.e/test.fastq.gz -o /net/cn-1/mnt/SCRATCH/princesstest/0406/2.without.e/statitics/raw_reads/reads_stat.txt -t 1
        
Activating conda environment: /net/cn-1/mnt/SCRATCH/princesstest/0406/2.without.e/.snakemake/conda/1b58da75
[Tue Apr  6 09:06:02 2021]
Finished job 0.
1 of 1 steps (100%) done
```

Comment: Can you try another rule/step?  It seems like it's an error in the rawcoverage.py script.

Comment: It would be helpful if you also shared the error log from job `12727829 ` that failed, because in the question it succeeded in another run "[Tue Apr  6 09:06:02 2021]
Finished job 0.
1 of 1 steps (100%) done"

Comment: I added the error annotation. Will try Troy's suggestion as well. Thank you.